# Prevent window from being clicked in while another window is open

Tags: c++, winapi

On Windows, when a window opens on top of another window, the parent window will not be clickable, and will make a "ding" sound and its titlebar will flash. It will do this until the other window is closed. How do I recreate this in Win32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words you are looking for are [modal and modeless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/modal-and-modeless-dialog-boxes?view=msvc-170).

*Modal* dialogs won't let the user interact with the parent window until they've been dismissed.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modal-dialog-box) document covers the Win32 API for creating modal dialogs.

Comment: Also, Raymond Chen's blog, [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/), did a whole series on [Modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/modality), you should have a read.

Comment: The *"parent window"* is called [owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows). Parent/child relationships are distinctly different from ownership.